# Is it possible to auto register in Castle Windsor based on naming convention?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

```
public interface IMySpecialService {}
public interface MySpecialService : IMySpecialService {}
```

Is it possible to register `MySpecialService` as the chosen implementation of `IMySpecialService` without having to specify details of either the interface or implementation? i.e. Can I configure Castle Windsor to use the interface name minus the `I`?

Answer (score 3):

This one should work for you:

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromThisAssembly()
        .InNamespace("YourNamespace")
        .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
);
```

More here:

https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md